# Would St. Cuthbert accept goblins and orcs as religious converts?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, religions-and-deities, warhammer

I'm playing a (LG) Cleric of St. Cuthbert in a D&D 3.5 game set in Warhammer's world.

In our adventures we came upon a group of goblins and orcs, who are basically evil creatures, but we kind of managed to set ourselves up as leaders of their pack and control them. I'm thinking of trying to convert them to a neutral alignment and see if they would adopt the religion of St. Cuthbert. However, I'm not sure that St. Cuthbert would even allow something like this to happen.

What's important to me is St. Cuthbert's religion's point of view on all of this. Should I even be considering trying to convert them into my religion, or would this go against the religion's rules or purpose?

Comment: Can you explain how your Warhammer Setting works? St. Cuthbert seems to be a D&D Deity, how does that fit in with Warhammer? I would have expected there would be priests of Sigmar in your World, no matter which rules you use.

Comment: There are priests of Sigmar in the Empire and it's considered to be a similar deity to St. Cuthbert.  St. Cuthbert is unknown religion in the Empire we might say and I'm trying to expand it. If it's easier, you may consider two options - either I'm a priest of Sigmar, or the setting isn't Warhammer but classic D&D.

Comment: Ask your DM. Ultimately, it's up to them.

Comment: I would recommend that you reframe your question to ask specifically about the beliefs of St. Cuthbert's religion, and add the "lore" tag to your question.  There is lore from various versions of D&D and AD&D for St Cuthbert, you have made a good choice to narrow the scope of  your question to the 3.5 edition of D&D and the lore from that setting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This Is Entirely World, Location, And Church Dependent**

Asking for a general answer is nonsensical. St. Cuthbert existing across game settings also doesn't really make sense - St. Cuthbert has a lot of established lore in Greyhawk that doesn't necessarily apply. And St. Cuthbert's clergy are notoriously hard headed, so if Prelate Whoever wants to or doesn't want to allow it then by Cuthbert that's what he's going to do.

**But No**

Again it sounds like you're in some weird bastardization of a world so only the GM can say, but in the Warhammer world humans do not have truck with orks and goblins, period.

If you just want St. Cuthbert lore in general then ask about that, [here's his Canonfire! page](http://www.canonfire.com/wiki/index.php?title=Saint_Cuthbert). Your topic is not addressed explicitly.

Comment: It may be addressed in the article by Sean Reynolds (Core Beliefs) in Dragon Magazine 358, but I don't have a copy of that issue.

Comment: "Saint Cuthbert hates evil, but is more concerned with law and order, with **converting the uninformed**, and preventing backsliding among the faithful." could give you a way in, but as mxyzplk says, the Warhammer world is very segregated.